# How to remove files with unusual extension?

Tags: windows, powershell

We have to work with an engineering program that generates lock files with the extension `.lck$`. I've tried various methods to clean these files nightly, with no luck. "$" being a system variable, I assume is the problem

Any ideas?

All of these have been tried:

```
Remove-Item c:\temp\*.lck$ -recurse

Get-ChildItem “C:\temp\” -recurse -include *.lck$ -force | remove-item

del *.lck$ /s /f

del *.lck* /s /f
```

Comment: Have you tried this: `Remove-Item c:\temp\*.lck$ -recurse` ? Please also edit your answer and include your current code.

Comment: I believe you only missed backslash in your first example `Remove-Item c:\temp*.lck$ -recurse` between folder path and filename.

Answer (score 0):

in powershell `rm -recurse '*.lck$'` should work.